# Webpack 4 watch content base not working

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using webpack 4.7 and for some reason the page isn't refreshing when I make changes. I can see my scss/css recompile but it doesn't trigger a refresh, the same for index.html

I'm using commands via the package.json:

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development --watch-content-base js/index.js --output dist/main.js"
```

I've also tried explicitly configuring the content base + watchContentBase:true in the webpack.config but still no joy.

Here's my config:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
devServer: {
    contentBase: [path.resolve(__dirname, "")],
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    overlay: true
},
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin('dist', {}),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "main.css"
    })
],
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        modules: false,
                        sourceMap: true,
                        importLoader: 2
                    }
                },
                "sass-loader"
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?emitFile=true&name=[path][name].[ext]'
        }
    ]
}
};
```

My content base is the root folder of the project, so not /app or whatever. Could this be the issue?

Thanks